# Build failed Xcode 10 cordova firebase project

Tags: xcode, firebase, cordova, cocoapods

I'm building a cordova project for iOS and I'm trying to add Firebase SDK. I installed Cocoapods as required, then I installed cordova-plugin-firebasex; I opened my .xcworkspace and changed Build settings in target as follows:

[Build settings detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIHX7.png)

Then ran `pod install` in platforms/ios folder, went to the root directory adn typed `sudo cordova prepare ios`; I updated the window in Xcode 10, went in Build Phases of target and checked the box 'Run scripts only when installing' as follows:

[checkbox focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMfl0.png)

I also tried to replace the original path, i.e.

```
diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
```

became like that:

```
diff "${SRCROOT}/Podfile.lock" "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
```

anyway I'm getting this error:

/Users/davide/Desktop/cordova-plugin-firebasex-test/platforms/ios/FirebaseTest/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebasex/AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.m:3:9: **'Firebase.h' file not found**

I tried do remove Podfile.lock and then `pod install`, tried to do `pod deintegrate` and `pod clean`, then again `pod install`, tried also `pod repo update`, I'm still stuck and fail to build my project for iOS.

Any suggestions?
Thanks, Davide

Comment: If you search for this error in **GitHub**, you'll find many threads with possible solutions, such as https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1847

Answer (score 7):

I has the same problem.

The problem was that the file "Firebase.h" was only a link to the real "Firebase.h" that was not installed in Cocoapods libraries. So the problem was with Cocoapods. Even run pod clean, pod install, ecc. didn't resolve, cause nowhere was written to install the libraries.

Then I noticed that the podfile was not correctly configured by the plugin.

So, try to open it (in XCODE, podfile in Pods folder) and verify that is something like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'your project' do
    project 'your project.xcodeproj'
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.3.0'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth', '6.3.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '6.3.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance', '6.3.0'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '6.3.0'
    pod 'Fabric', '1.9.0'
    pod 'Crashlytics', '3.12.0'
end
```

If not, try to write it manually, then go to your platforms/ios folder and run `pod install`. Now you can notice that Cocoapods install all the libraries.

I has also some other little problem compiling, but, after this operations, removing the plugin and reinstalling it resolved them.

I hope this can help.