# 'Firebase/Firebase.h' file not found after trying everything

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

[image]

I have this error when trying to build a React Native project on iOS:

> 'Firebase/Firebase.h' file not found

I already have `#import <Firebase.h>` in AppDelegate.m which works just fine, but this error appear in react-native-firebase module
My issue's description is similar to this https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1847

I followed all the comments of that thread plus every other thread that I could find online, with no success.

Tried with and without Cocoa.

Changed search framework path and header path.

Deleted pods file, caches, pod update, pod install, and so many things.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I have to mention again that Firebase.h import from AppDelegate works just fine.

Comment: Similar problem. Try to look my answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218066/build-failed-xcode-10-cordova-firebase-project/58044569#58044569](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218066/build-failed-xcode-10-cordova-firebase-project/58044569#58044569)